# Add an array as JSON in an object PHP

Tags: php, objective-c

I have an iPhone code as follow

```
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
[database open];
NSString *sqlSelectQuery = @"SELECT * FROM drinks";

// Query result
FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:sqlSelectQuery];
while([results next])
{
    Drinks *drink = [[Drinks alloc] init];

    [drink setDrinkId:[results intForColumn:@"id"]];
    [drink setVenueId:[results intForColumn:@"venueId"]];
    [drink setName:[results stringForColumn:@"name"]];
    [drink setType:[results intForColumn:@"venueId"]];

    NSMutableArray *servingSizes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *sqlSelectQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM servingSizes WHERE drinkId = %d", drink.drinkId];

    FMResultSet *servingResult = [database executeQuery:sqlSelectQuery];
    while([servingResult next])
    {
        Servings *serving = [[Servings alloc] init];

        [serving setDrinkId:[servingResult intForColumn:@"drinkId"]];
        [serving setServingId:[servingResult intForColumn:@"id"]];
        [serving setServingSize:[servingResult intForColumn:@"servingSize"]];
        [serving setPrice:[servingResult intForColumn:@"price"]];

        [servingSizes addObject:serving];
    }

    [drink setServingsArray:servingSizes];
    [drinksArray addObject:drink];
}
```

Essentially this code reads a builtin database and create an Object DRINK and from the id of drink gets array of objects Servings from table.

Pretty easy thing however , i want to do the following thing in Php server side.

Here is my code

```
function GetAllDrinks() 
    {   
        try {

            $conn = $this->GetDBConnection();

            $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM drinks');
            $statement->execute();

            if(!($row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) 
            {
                return false;
            }

            foreach($row as $drink)
            {
               $drinkId  = $row->id;                
               $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM servingTable WHERE id = :drinkId)');

                $statement->bindParam(':drinkId' , $drinkId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $statement->execute();

                if(($serve = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) 
                {
                    // WHAT TO DO HERE
                }
            }

            $conn = null;
            return $row;

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
                throw $e;
        }   
        return $row;
    }
```

Now i want to create a JSON String for all but I am not sure How can I add servings in the drinks object? I Would like someone to help here since i am not an expert of PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Add &-sign to create a reference to $drinks
foreach($row as &$drink)
{
   $drinkId  = $row->id;                
   $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM servingTable WHERE id = :drinkId)');

    $statement->bindParam(':drinkId' , $drinkId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();

    if(($serve = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) 
    {
        $drink['servings'] = $serve;
    }
}
```

Now the `$row` should have all drinks and each drink will have a field `servings`. To get JSON:

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

Comment: Thanks that would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use prepare() in a loop, this method is very slow and it is done to prepare a query only one time.

```
// Add &-sign to create a reference to $drinks
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM servingTable WHERE id = :drinkId)');
$statement->bindParam(':drinkId' , $drinkId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
foreach($row as &$drink) {
    $drinkId  = $row->id;
    $statement->execute();//According to documentation

    if(($serve = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) 
    {
        $drink['servings'] = $serve;
    }
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
(I should use it too but it's managed by a one by one query system, it requires improvements)